# is it correct to use "i need answered"?

Tags: grammar

Hello I came across this sentence:

- "*i have questions i need answered*"

Is it correct to use **answered** after **need**?

in my opinion, there should be something like :

- "*i have questions i need answers*" or
- "*i have questions i need to be answered*"

I tried to Google but did not find the rules of this, I know that there is only *have something done*, so I want to understand this is an mistake or is it right?
Thanks

Comment: Think of it as a shortened version of "I have questions **that** I need answered."  We often drop *that* in relative clauses: https://englishharmony.com/omitting-relative-pronouns/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have questions I need answered.

Yes, this is a perfectly grammatical sentence. *answered* in this sentence is an adjective (precisely, a predicative complement).

Regarding the other version of this sentence, you must add the preposition *of* or *to* and write:

> I have questions i need answers **of**/**to.**

Why **of**/**to** is mandated above is because a preposition takes an *object*, which in this case is *questions.* Otherwise, the syntax of the sentence is dubious. Please note that *(which) I have* is a reduced relative clause modifying *questions.*

The third version is totally incorrect and should therefore be avoided.

Comment: thanks for the good explanation